# UIAlertView subview positioning

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uialertview

I have an alertView which pops up when a user is changing tabs

```
UIAlertView *tempAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Video?" 
                                                    message:@"Do you wish to save the video ?" 
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil];
[tempAlert show];
[tempAlert setDelegate:self];
self.saveAlert = tempAlert;
[tempAlert release];
```

Now i handle the button click event and in this event i want to show another alert with a progressView as a subview

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Save Video?"])
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) 
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]; //17.4.12
        // Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
        indicator.center = CGPointMake(self.saveAlert.bounds.size.width / 2, self.saveAlert.bounds.size.height - 40);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [self.saveAlert addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator release];
        [(ImageCanvas1AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setMainAlert:self.saveAlert];


        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(performSaveOperationWithTabChangeToIndex:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.tab]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playMovie)
                               withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
else
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) 
    {
        [self.videoGenerator cancelVideoGeneration];
    }
}
}
```

if the user does touch the save button i show an alertView with a progressView as a subview
this method is called in the 'playMovie' method

```
- (void)showAlert
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Generating Video" 
                                                message:@"Please wait!" 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show)
                        withObject:nil
                     waitUntilDone:YES];
[alert setDelegate:self];
self.videoAlert = alert;
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(alert.bounds.size.width - progressView.bounds.size.width - 95,
                                  alert.bounds.size.height - progressView.bounds.size.height - 80, 
                                  progressView.bounds.size.width, 
                                  progressView.bounds.size.height)];
[alert addSubview:progressView];
self.progressView = progressView;
[progressView release];

[alert release];

[pool release];
}
```

the problem is :

If i show the alertView normally the subviews positioning is fine

but if i show the alertView in the

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{`

it position of the progressView is improper

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to show progress inside a uialertview ? UIalertviews are modal. Make your own view and show that instead, that way you are in total control, you can add a pause, continue and stop buttons, you can display all the information you want.

Comment: You don't have to make a modal view unless you want to lock the app. Easiest is to make a fullscreen view that is like 70% transparent, black background for example. The size may be whatever you prefer. The trouble with doing things modally is that the whole app stops

Comment: Here is an example of what you can very easily accomplish, which enables you to easily add background tasks. Much simpler. http://www.code4app.com/photo/4f67fccc6803faaa75000001_1.png